# What caused the leaf scorch on my Dracaena deremensis 'Lemon Lime' and what should I do about it?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, leaves, plant-care, dracaena

I have a [*Dracaena deremensis* 'Lemon Lime'](http://www.exoticangel.com/plant-library/species/dracaena/item/221-lemon-lime) in my office. Several month ago it began to show leaf scorches.

The gardener that sold it suggested it could be a symptom of sun burns.

I then moved the plant to a spot where no direct sunlight is coming in.

The plant also shows some yellowish spots (see pictures).

What could it be? What should I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just bought one of these plants at a garden sale and it has the same leaf decay as your plant. Did you ever find out how to treat it. If so can you give me advice as it's a lovely plant and I would like to prevent it for getting worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check for red spider mite infestation, which sometimes causes these yellow spots - they are quite difficult to see. Spray with an appropriate pesticide spray if you find them. Second, these plants are said to be sensitive to fluoride in water, so if your tapwater is fluoridated and you've been using that, this might cause those brown tips, though usually the brown tips have a yellow band on the 'live' end so to speak.

The other possible cause of the yellow spots is poor drainage - do you leave the plant standing in any outer container which collects water? If so, ensure you empty the container 30 minutes after watering. Water only when the surface of the compost is slightly dry to the touch, but not so dry it's shrunken from the sides of the pot, and water thoroughly. Despite not liking sitting in water, these plants don't like to dry out and do like high humidity in the air - keep away from direct heat sources, and add a pebble tray if you think it's necessary. (Pebble tray - an outer tray larger than the pot, filled with pebbles, that you keep half full of water, so the bottom of the pot is on the pebbles but above the water - the water evaporates and keeps the air round the plant more humid). Keep the plant in an even temperature as far as possible, never below 65 deg F, and, as you've already done, out of direct sunlight.

Lastly, check whether its pot bound - I have one of these and mine's developed dry brown patches on the leaves, largely because I haven't repotted it and the pot's way too small, so it can't hang on to enough water.

Comment: I checked for red spider mites and did not find any. I will try with less watering as it could be the problem.

Answer (score 5):

There is more to it than just over watering. I have seen these symptoms over and over again with dracaena.  The top picture with it's growth rings is symptomatic of a [fungus or bacterial](http://extension.psu.edu/pests/plant-diseases/all-fact-sheets/dracaena-diseases) disease.  The triggering factor for this is normally a period of [over watering](http://pnwhandbooks.org/plantdisease/dracaena-leaf-spots).  This stresses the plants and provides the right environment in the soil for the fungus or bacteria to take hold.  As long as wet conditions continue you will see dead or necrotic spots start and grow in semi circular areas or up and down a leaf vein.

Other factors which can stress the plant include fluoride levels in the water which gradually build up and cause similar dead areas on the leaf.

Solution:

- keep the plant drier, as @Bamboo says do not let sit in water
- give the plant more light
- this suggestion goes against the grain but I find soil less mixes based on peat have a shorter life than top soil mixes.  As the organic matter is used up the mix is unable to buffer the dissolved salts in the tap water most people use.  If you have access to topsoil that is free of weeds and pathogens consider top dressing the plant with it.
- Edit: a fungicide might help but further reading of the safety data sheet would be in order

Comment: I will try with a treatment against fungi but more light will be difficult because of the weather (I live in Zurich, Switzerland, and in winter the insulation is not really ideal :-)